# SVM machine learning - How to define the target in the training set?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I am working on a project where I have to implement SVM machine learning algorithm. I am trying to predict the forearm movement intention. I am using accelometer (attached to my forearm) for measuring the angle change for x,y,z axes. I have never used machine before. The problem I am having is I do not exactly know how to structure the training set. I know the angle changes for each of the axis and I know i.e if x=45 degrees, y = 65 degrees, z=30 degrees gesture performed i performed is flexion. I would like to implement 3 gestures.So the data I am having is :

x y z Target

20 60 90 flexion

100 63 23 internal rotation

89 23 74 twist

. . . .

I have a file with around 2000 entries. I know I have to normalize the training set so the data are scaled. I would like to scale it so they are in this range [0.9, 0.1]. The problem I am having is I do not know how to represent the target in my training set. Can I just use random numbers as 1 for flexion, 2 for internal rotation, 3 for twist??

Also once the training is completed can I do the predictions based on values for x,y,z only?? without having to supply the target value. Is my understanding correct??

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

> The problem I am having is I do not know how to represent the target in my training set. Can I just use random numbers as 1 for flexion, 2 for internal rotation, 3 for twist??

This depends on the software you're using. In e1071 for R, you could just read in the file as-is and work with the labels as factors.

> Also once the training is completed can I do the predictions based on values for x,y,z only?? without having to supply the target value. Is my understanding correct??

Yes, prediction is done without the class labels. The reason we use SVMs and similar technology to make predictions is because the class labels aren't available. If they were available, we would use the class labels.

Comment: I am using python. I have imported svm from sklearn.                        http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html

Comment: @userMilka I guess you'll have to learn how to use python, then.

Comment: I went through the tutorial for svm. I used python for different projects in the past. I have training data stored in excel sheet I can import the data into  python. Just do not know how to represent them. I know i need to normalize the data before feeding it to learning algorithm. I just do not know how to represent the target data .(as i described in my question)

Comment: Questions about how to use software are off-topic here. http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic